# Vector quantization for categorical data

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

Software for vector quantization usually works only on numerical data.  One example of this is Python's `scipy.cluster.vq.vq` ([here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.vq.html#scipy.cluster.vq.vq)), which performs vector quantization.  The numerical data requirement also shows up for most clustering software.

Many have pointed out that you can always convert a categorical variable to a set of binary numeric variables.  But this becomes awkward when working with big data where an individual categorical variable  may have hundreds or thousands of categories.

The obvious alternative is to change the distance function.  With mixed data types, the distance from an observation to a "center" or "codebook entry" could be expressed as a two-part sum involving (a) the usual Euclidean calculation for the numeric variables and (b) the sum of inequality indicators for categorical variables, as proposed [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-11819-7_10#page-1) on page 125.

Is there any open-source software implementation of vector quantization with such a generalized distance function?

Comment: While one can use a lot of existing code for this sort of problem (as you've noted) my experience is that the distance function almost always has to be written specifically to suit the data in a particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "quantize" categorial data.

Recall *definitions* of quantization ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quantize)):

> 1. To limit the number of possible values of a quantity, or states of a system, by applying the rules of quantum mechanics
> 2. To approximate a *continuously varying* signal by one whose amplitude can only have a set of *discrete* values

In other words, quantization means **converting a *continuous* variable into a *discrete* variable**. Vector quantization does the same, for multiple variables at the same time.

However, **categorial variables *already* are discrete**.

What you seem to be looking for is a prototype-based clustering algorithm for categorial data (maybe STING and COOLCAT? I don't know if they will produce prototypes); but this isn't "vector quantization" anymore.

I believe that very often, **frequent itemset mining** is actually the best approach to find prototypes/archetypes of categorial data.

As for clustering algorithms that allow other distance functions - there are plenty. [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) has a lot of such algorithms, and also a [tutorial on implementing a custom distance](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/DistanceFunctions). But this is Java, not Python. I'm pretty sure at least *some* of the clustering algorithms in scipy to allow custom distances, too.

Now pythons `scipy.cluster.vq.vq` is *really* simple code. You do not need a library for that at all. The main job of this function is wrapping a C implementation which runs much faster than python code... if you look at the `py_vq` version (which is used when the C version cannot be used), is is really simple code... essentially, for every object `obs[i]` it calls this function:

```
code[i] = argmin(np.sum((obs[i] - code_book) ** 2, 1))
```

Now you obviously can't use Euclidean distance with a categorial codebook; but translating this line to whatever similarity you want is not hard.

The harder part usually is *constructing* the codebook, not using it.

Comment: I completely agree that I abused the word "quantize".  I probably started thinking in that way because I am looking for a slight extension/generalization of the `scipy.cluster.vq.vq` quantization algorithm implementation.

Comment: `scipy.cluster.vq.vq` is only the application of a codebook; this is rather trivial to do yourself once you have defined *similarity*. The harder part usually is building the codebook...

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to do is very simple conceptually.  In this case I need well-optimized code to work on big data.  Time to get more comfortable with Cython and/or C.

Answer (score 1):

For machine learning and clustering algorithms you can also find useful [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/). To achieve what you want, you can have a look to their implementation of [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.dbscan.html#sklearn.cluster.dbscan).

In their documentation, you can find:

```
sklearn.cluster.dbscan(X, eps=0.5, min_samples=5, metric='minkowski', algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, p=2, random_state=None)
```

Here `X` can be either your already computed distance matrix (and passing `metric='precomputed'`) or the standard `samples x features` matrix, while `metric=` can be a string (with the identifier of one of the already implemented [distance functions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html)) or a callable python function that will compute distances in a pair-wise fashion.

If you can't find the metric you want, you can always program it as a python function:

```
def mydist(a, b):
    return a - b # the metric you want comes here
```

And call `dbscan` with `metric=mydist`. Alternatively, you can calculate your distance matrix previously, and pass it to the clustering algorith.

There are some other clustering algorithms in the same library, have a look at them [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cluster).